# Jest Issue for testing a component mapping over a json structure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, next.js, ts-jest

I have created a Next Function Component which basically maps over a json file using the values within creating a load of  tags values as seen below.

```
import FooterCerts from "constants/json/FooterCerts.json";
import { NextFunctionComponent } from "next";
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./index.scss";

export const FooterLogos: NextFunctionComponent = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <style jsx={styles.toString()}>{styles}</style>
    <ul>
      {FooterCerts.map((logo) => (
        <a
          href={logo.HREF}
          title={logo.TITLE}
          rel="noopener external"
          target="_blank"
          data-qa={logo.DATA_QA}
          key={logo.KEY}
        >
          <li>
            <img src={logo.FILE_PATH} alt={logo.ALT} />
          </li>
        </a>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

My issue comes when creating the unit test for this component. It is a basic test just trying to create a snapshot.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { cleanup, render } from "react-testing-library";
import { FooterLogos } from ".";

afterEach(cleanup);

it("renders as expected", () => {
  const { container } = render(<FooterLogos />);

  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This causes an issue when running this test of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I am using Jest latest version of 24.1.0, ts-jest of 24.0.0 with the jest config of:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testRegex: "(/src/.*)\\.(test.tsx?)$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.*\\.scss$": __dirname + "/jest.stub.ts",
    "^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1",
    "^helpers(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/helpers$1",
    "^pages(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/pages$1",
    "^services(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/services$1",
    "^state(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/state$1",
    "^fixtures(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/fixtures$1",
    "^constants(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/constants$1",
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.ts"],
};
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue would be great or if anything other information is required to help please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing the jest config from:

```
transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
```

to:

```
transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
```